Can't parse MQTT messages directly from the Broker topic
I am a novice of java as well as the whole spring framework. I am trying to develop an application in SpringBoot to be used in an MQTT context.
The application consists of two microservices: the first that retrieves data from a broker and saves it to a database, and the second exposes endpoints to allow users to retrieve and perform operations on some kind of data.
The problem is in the first microservice, called DataRetriever, which has to deal with reading weather messages (written in json format) from a topic (weather-data) on a Mosquitto broker and contextually parse them to then save the json fields into proper tables within Postgres.
Basically I can't find a proper way of feeding the message payloads from the topic to the Object Mapper.
The entire logic I've built is based onto two files:

MqttBeans where I handle the connection logic going in and out of the broker channels, the code is this one:

package com.example.demo.configs;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageProducer;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.MqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.MqttPahoMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.support.DefaultPahoMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.support.MqttHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;

/**
 * Setting up MQTT Client connection configurations
 * the Client Factory
 * the Channels: Inbound + Outbound
 * the Message Handler
 */

@Configuration
public class MqttBeans {

    // Client Factory (factory configs)
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();

        // Options Settings
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] {"tcp://localhost:1883"});
        //options.setUserName("postgres");
        //String password = "12345678";
        //options.setPassword(password.toCharArray());
        options.setCleanSession(true);

        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);

        return factory;
    }

    // Inbound Ch (Subscribing)
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("serverIn", mqttClientFactory(),"#");
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(2);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());

        return adapter;
    }

    // Msg Handler
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

                // Topic
                String topic = message.getHeaders().get(MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC).toString(); // retrieving the topic from the message header
                if (topic.equals("weather-data")) {
                    System.out.println("Here's the topic: " + topic); // printing out the topic
                }
                // Payload
                String payload = message.getPayload().toString();
                System.out.println("Here's the payload: " + payload); // printing out any msg that comes in the ch
            }
        };
    }

    // Outbound Ch (Publishing)
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttOutboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Msg Handler
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
    public MessageHandler mqttOutbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("serverOut", mqttClientFactory());
        messageHandler.setAsync(true); // so that the client will always be up and listening
        messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("weather-data");
        messageHandler.setDefaultRetained(false);

        return messageHandler;
    }
}





StartupUtility which should take care of parsing the messages that are written on the broker topic, mapping them (with the objectMapper) to what is written in my CityEntity and creating and populating the tables in postgres (with the data that it read during the parsing of the json fields)

The problem is that, as you can see from the code written in StartupUtility
package com.example.demo.startup;

import com.example.demo.entities.CityEntity;
import com.example.demo.repos.CityWeatherRepo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

// Implementing CommandLineRunnerInterface to be init when proj is created
@Component
@Log
public class StartupUtility implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    // Passing the json as a value to test the parsing logic
    @Value("${demo.json.string}") private String json;

    // Wiring the Inbound ch
    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel mqttInputChannel;

    // Wiring the Repo
    @Autowired private CityWeatherRepo repo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        // Init Obj Mapper instance
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Avoiding failure in case of unrecognized fields during json mapping
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        // Getting the json + Converting into the City Class
        CityEntity value = mapper.readValue(json, CityEntity.class); // replace json with payload // input: json in string format, output: OpenAPI/CityEntity (class)

        // Saving
        CityEntity save = repo.save(value);

        // Checking the Saving process
        log.info(" Entity info " + save.toString());
    }
}

the json I'm going to parse is hardcoded into a dedicated variable "demo.json.string", written in the application.properties file (I did this to see if at least the parsing logic is correct, and it is) , while I want the jsons to be the ones that are written in the topic (weather-data) like this:
{"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":291.47,"feels_like":290.74,"temp_min":289.18,"temp_max":292.64,"pressure":1009,"humidity":53},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.14,"deg":140},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1714483329,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2075535,"country":"GB","sunrise":1714451607,"sunset":1714504902},"timezone":3600,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
{"coord":{"lon":2.3488,"lat":48.8534},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":291.56,"feels_like":291.21,"temp_min":290.03,"temp_max":292.64,"pressure":1012,"humidity":67},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.69,"deg":140},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1714483519,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2012208,"country":"FR","sunrise":1714451474,"sunset":1714503847},"timezone":7200,"id":2988507,"name":"Paris","cod":200}
{"coord":{"lon":-85.1647,"lat":34.257},"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":289.27,"feels_like":289.29,"temp_min":288.15,"temp_max":290.93,"pressure":1018,"humidity":90},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.54,"deg":20},"rain":{"1h":5.05},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1714483081,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2038061,"country":"US","sunrise":1714474288,"sunset":1714523036},"timezone":-14400,"id":4219762,"name":"Rome","cod":200}
{"coord":{"lon":13.4105,"lat":52.5244},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":301.22,"feels_like":300.5,"temp_min":299.81,"temp_max":302.53,"pressure":1004,"humidity":34},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.66,"deg":150},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1714483328,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2011538,"country":"DE","sunrise":1714448171,"sunset":1714501842},"timezone":7200,"id":2950159,"name":"Berlin","cod":200}
{"coord":{"lon":-74.006,"lat":40.7143},"weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":286.43,"feels_like":286.14,"temp_min":284.84,"temp_max":287.62,"pressure":1015,"humidity":89},"visibility":9656,"wind":{"speed":7.2,"deg":50},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1714483436,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2008101,"country":"US","sunrise":1714470912,"sunset":1714521057},"timezone":-14400,"id":5128581,"name":"New York","cod":200}

My idea was to inject into StartupUtility the channel and be able to pass the payload (?) as a parameter, but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to address this or have any newbie-suggestions to structure the code differently from a logic pov?

Please do not post images of text (the json), images are hard read, impossible to search or for people that use screen readers. Please post the actual text and format it like code.

ok, sorry for that & thank you for the advice.
Just edited the md in a better way.

[UPDATE]: Turns out it was simpler than I thought, I will premise, however, that I had to abandon the idea of putting my json mapping/parsing function into a utility using CommandLineRunner, in favor of a simpler and more intuitive class named MessageParser, whose code is as follows:
package com.example.demo.utils;

import com.example.demo.entities.CityEntity;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MessageParser {

    /**
     * NOTE: It is good practice to include in the method name the type of obj that the method will return/handle.
     * In this case, the 'parse' method accepts a message payload and returns a CityEntity.
     * Thereby, the 'CityEntity' obj will then be manipulated by the message handler of the 'MqttBeans' class
     */

    // Parsing fn
    public static CityEntity parse(String msg_payload) throws Exception {
        // Init Obj Mapper instance
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Avoiding failure in case of unrecognized fields during json mapping, a workaround may be the 'Mixin' feature from the Jackson pckg
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        // Retrieving the payload + Converting into the CityEntity class
        return mapper.readValue(msg_payload, CityEntity.class);
    }
}

At the same time, the logic of the MqttBeans class has also changed, more specifically the one of its Bean MessageHandler, which now calls the 'parse' (static) method thus using MessageParser; here is how it has changed:
[...] 

// Wiring City repo
@Autowired
private CityWeatherRepo repo;

// Msg Handler
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        // Handling msg, once it's received
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            // Topic
            String topic = message.getHeaders().get(MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC).toString(); // retrieving the topic from the message header
            if (topic.equals("weather-data")) {
                System.out.println("The topic related to this message is: \n" + topic); // printing out the topic
            }
            // Payload
            String payload = message.getPayload().toString();
            System.out.println("The message payload is: \n" + payload); // printing out any msg that comes in the ch
            try {
                // Parsing + Saving
                CityEntity value = MessageParser.parse(payload);
                CityEntity save = repo.save(value);

                // Checking the Saving process
                log.info("\nEntity infos for the parsed payload: \n" + save.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}

[...] 

By doing this I am able to have the logics separated into two different classes.
If anyone has any suggestions on this, on how to do it more efficiently and clean, please feel free to write and submit them.
